# ORA-00942 when trying to select from gv$session inside of procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have been tasked with allowing developers to kill their own sessions in the Development database. I've written a procedure, but for some reason I'm getting `PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` when trying to call `gv$session`. Here's the proc, being compiled as `SYSTEM`. Running on an 11.2.0.4.3, 2 node RAC database:

```
create or replace procedure kill_dev_session (v_osname in varchar2)
is
  lv_env     VARCHAR2(30 char);
  li_inst_id number;
  li_sid     number;
  li_serial  number;
begin
  select replace(global_name, '.DOMAIN.COM', '') 
    into lv_env
    from global_name;

  select inst_id, sid, serial#
    into li_inst_id, li_sid, li_serial
    from sys.gv$session
   where upper(osuser) = upper(v_osname)
  group by inst_id, sid, serial#;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION'||''||li_sid||','||li_serial||','||li_inst_id||'''';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = ''127.0.0.1''';
  UTL_MAIL.send(sender => lv_env||'@db01.domain.com',
              recipients => 'dba@domain.com',
              subject => 'Session killed by '||v_osname||' user in '||lv_env,
              message => 'This user killed a session using the kill_dev_session procedure.',
            mime_type => 'text; charset=us-ascii');

end;
/
```

So here's the rub: every single developer logs in with the same user, so I can't really use `username`. I don't want to open up blanket `alter system` for every single user. This would allow a dev manager to pass in a username (i.e. jsmith) and kill that session, and would email us DBAs that this happened, so we can see if the devs are doing this a lot.

Any thoughts as to why I'm seeing this:
    Errors for PROCEDURE KILL_DEV_SESSION:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
12/3     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
14/10    PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try running this query and returning the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON gv_$session TO system;
```

Because you are accessing a sys table by system in a stored 
procedure you need a direct grant on the underlying table.

Comment: Damn, is it that simple? I'll check this out, thanks Gandolf.

Comment: Didn't work:11:00:26 sys@DEV> grant select on gv_$session to system;`

Grant succeeded.

Comment: Grr. Didn't work: `11:00:26 sys@DEV> grant select on gv_$session to system; Grant succeeded.`

`11:00:47 system@DEV> alter procedure kill_dev_session compile; Warning: Procedure altered with compilation errors.`

Same error. Sorry for the formatting in this comment.

Comment: Try running this query and returning the results: SET LINESIZE 100
COL text FORMAT A80 WORD WRAP
SELECT line, text
  FROM dba_errors
 WHERE owner = 'SYSTEM'
   AND name  = 'KILL_DEV_SESSION'
 ORDER BY 1;

Comment: 11:26:23 system@DEV> SELECT line, text FROM dba_errors WHERE owner = 'SYSTEM' AND name = 'KILL_DEV_SESSION' ORDER BY 1;

      LINE TEXT
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 12 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
 14 PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Elapsed: 00:00:00.17

Comment: You must have run the query as a non privileged user. Do you have the rights to create a stored procedure as system? Ultimately your issue is caused by a lack of rights. You can try changing dba_errors to user_errors, but unless you log in as the owner of the stored procedure, it won't work. You need this to run as a privileged user for it to work.

Comment: Try running "select * from all_dependencies where owner='SYSTEM' and name='KILL_DEV_SESSION' order by 4,5,6;" to see what dependencies the stored procedure has and make sure that it has the proper rights.

Comment: `15:05:09 system@DEV> select count(*) from gv$session;` returns 248 rows. In order to select from the underlying `gv_$session`, I have to preface it with `sys.`, but I'm doing that in the procedure anyway. And this is compiled as `SYSTEM`, and I'm just trying to validate it, also as system.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Tom Kyte has the answer: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:22541885338185

Gandolf, you were technically correct according to what Tom responds with, but for whatever reason (bug? user error?) I couldn't get that to work.

So I tried the workaround:

```
15:09:47 system@DEV> drop procedure system.kill_dev_session;

Procedure dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.76
15:12:37 system@DEV> exit;
captjackvane@TomServo:~$ sqlplus sys@dev as sysdba

15:12:50 sys@DEV> create or replace procedure kill_dev_session (v_osname in varchar2)
is
 lv_env     VARCHAR2(30 char);
begin
  select replace(global_name, '.LEANLOGISTICS.COM', '') 
    into lv_env
    from global_name;

  FOR rec IN (select inst_id, sid, serial#
                from sys.gv$session
               where upper(osuser) = upper(v_osname)
              group by inst_id, sid, serial#)
  LOOP

  dbms_output.put_line('ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''||rec.sid||','||rec.serial#||','||rec.inst_id||'''');

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''||rec.sid||','||rec.serial#||','||rec.inst_id||'''';
  END LOOP;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = ''127.0.0.1''';

  UTL_MAIL.send(sender => lv_env||'@silver01.leanlogistics.com',
                recipients => 'dba@leanlogistics.com',
                subject => 'Session killed by '||v_osname||' user in '||lv_env,
                message => 'This user killed a session using the kill_dev_session procedure.',
                mime_type => 'text; charset=us-ascii');

end;
/

    Procedure created.

    Elapsed: 00:00:01.63
    15:12:52 sys@DEV> create public synonym kill_dev_session for sys.kill_dev_session;

    Synonym created.

    Elapsed: 00:00:00.80

    15:12:52 sys@DEV> grant execute on kill_dev_session to system;

    Grant succeeded.

    Elapsed: 00:00:00.80
```

This is working now. Of course, as you can see, I also had to change the inner sql to be a loop, because this wouldn't work if a user had logged in with 2+ session.

Additionally, it still isn't working because the very act of querying is doing a parallel query, which means that there are a whole bunch of "ghost" session ids that only exist at the time of the query, resulting in this procedure returning:

```
15:47:43 system@DEV> exec sys.kill_dev_session('captjackvane');
BEGIN sys.kill_dev_session('captjackvane'); END;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00026: missing or invalid session ID
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KILL_DEV_SESSION", line 17
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

But hey, what is life without a challenge? I'll work on that, then perhaps post another question to the forum if I can't resolve the issue myself. Thanks for the help.